# How to read a mixed text file and extract numbers only

Tags: fortran, stringreader

I need to read the output of one of my simulators and store the values. the file name is `forces.dat` and contains a similar thing as the following:

```
# Forces     
# CofR       : (4.750000e-01 3.500000e-02 2.000000e-02)
# Time       forces(pressure viscous porous) moment(pressure viscous porous)
2.633022e-02    ((6.268858e-02 -1.468850e+01 1.542745e-20) (1.000906e-03 8.405854e-06 -5.657665e-17) (0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00)) ((-8.779466e-18 8.442993e-19 -3.225599e-03) (-2.082489e-18 4.435609e-18 -1.572485e-03) (0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00))
8.095238e-02    ((1.781333e-01 -1.468455e+01 -3.545427e-19) (2.362118e-03  2.014609e-05 1.691584e-16) (0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00))  ((-3.344781e-18 -5.448339e-19 2.227502e-02) (5.092628e-18 -3.538718e-18  -1.203074e-03) (0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00))
1.600000e-01    ((3.204471e-01 -1.467482e+01 -4.599174e-18) (6.936764e-03 1.303800e-04 4.836650e-17) (0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00)) ((-1.123589e-17 -4.344967e-19 5.591623e-02) (1.532415e-18 -1.345592e-18  -9.550750e-04) (0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00))
```

I want to know how should I write a Fortran subroutine to ignore the first 3 lines and then read the number of next lines and then the values of each line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet which will keep a track of line numbers. Based on your requirement and nature of file, you can get the values of respective lines and can do the required.

```
string CurrentLine; 
int LastLineNumber;   
void NextLine() 
{
// using will make sure the file is closed
using(System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader ("c:\\forces.dat"))
{
    // Skip lines
    for (int i=0;i<LastLineNumber;++i)
        file.ReadLine();

    // Store your line
    CurrentLine = file.ReadLine();
    LastLineNumber++;
}
}
```

In the above code, inside `for` loop you can put in your logic of file processing based on the lines you want to read.

Comment: Thanks Lara. Isn't it a C code? I need a fortran code in my program now.

Comment: you have no where mentioned about fortran. May be you can apply same logic with fortran too

Answer (score 1):

Although I think it is easier to preprocess the file by some command-line tool (e.g. `sed -e 's/(/ /g' -e 's/)/ /g' input.dat`), we can also use Fortran directly by reading each line into a long character string and removing all the unnecessary parentheses:

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: mxline = 5000  !! choose appropriately
    integer i, ios, finp, nl
    character(500) str
    real, save :: time( mxline )
    real, dimension( 3, mxline ), save :: &
            frc_pres, frc_visc, frc_poro, &
            mom_pres, mom_visc, mom_poro

    finp = 10
    open( finp, file="input.dat", status="old" )

    nl = 0
    do
        read( finp, "(a)", iostat=ios ) str
        if ( ios /= 0 ) exit
        str = trim( adjustL( str ) )

        !! Skip comment or blank lines.
        if ( str(1:1) == "#" .or. str == "" ) cycle

        !! Replace parentheses with space.
        do i = 1, len_trim( str )
            if ( str(i:i) == "(" .or. str(i:i) == ")" ) str(i:i) = " "
        enddo

        !! Read data from the string.
        nl = nl + 1
        read( str, * ) time( nl ), &
                       frc_pres( :, nl ), frc_visc( :, nl ), frc_poro( :, nl ), &
                       mom_pres( :, nl ), mom_visc( :, nl ), mom_poro( :, nl )
    enddo

    close( finp )

    !! Check.
    do i = 1, nl
        print *
        print *, "time = ", time( i )
        print *, "frc_pres = ", frc_pres( :, i )
        print *, "frc_visc = ", frc_visc( :, i )
        print *, "frc_poro = ", frc_poro( :, i )
        print *, "mom_pres = ", mom_pres( :, i )
        print *, "mom_visc = ", mom_visc( :, i )
        print *, "mom_poro = ", mom_poro( :, i )
    enddo

end program
```

If the data values can become very large (say, 1.0e100), please consider using double-precision reals so as not to loose necessary precision.

Comment: Thanks roygvib. It works perfect. Although I wrote another program but this one is much faster.